# Process request sequentially

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs6

The main goal is process my requests sequentially. I have input for scanning values by scanner in fast order. But sometimes server returns data slowly and if i scanning very fast, server is fell down and returns 500. My idea is process this request sequentially. I tried to find some solutions, but i don't found what i want. I don't know if i should use some interceptor, or save it in service or component.

I tried to find solution in interceptor, but there i don't found out when request is done and interceptor can process next request. I tried to use rxjs operators, but i don;t know how to incorporate to my solution. This is example what i want to in my solution

```
from([1, 2, 3, 4])
  .pipe(
    concatMap(param =>
      this.http.get(
        `http://localhost:6013/api/v1/test/buffer?data=${param}`
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

from operator make observable of my requests and ConcatMap process it sequentially

There is my skeleton app

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  form = this.fb.group({
    input: ['', Validators.required]
  });

  makeRequest$ = new Subject();
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  onSubmit() {
    this.http
      .get(
        `http://localhost:6013/api/v1/test/buffer?data=${
          this.form.controls.input.value
        }`
      )
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
      });

    this.form.reset();
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

app.interceptor.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AppInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  arrayRequest: Array<HttpRequest<any>> = [];

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

app.components.html

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <label>
    Data:
    <input type="text" formControlName="input" />
  </label>

  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I excepted something like code above. ConcatMap process request sequentially, but i don't know how i should work with requests and how direction i should to choice.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do, but it seems to me that the Interceptor would not be useful for this.  `concatMap` is indeed what will force the requests to be made sequentially, so you are on the right track there.  Your example simply shows a form input being used to drive the requests - what does your scan code look like?  I'm guessing that code would return a value asynchronously which you want to then feed into a source observable that is then contacMap'd into the http request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your problem you need to sequentially execute api requests onSubmit. **In your case you need rxjs Subject to achieve expected behavior**. I modified your component so you can have a look at ngOnInit and onSubmit functions.

> makeRequest$ is now Observable, where new events arrive on every
>   onSubmit method call. You can use concatMap to sequentially send api
>   requests and also you can use delay operator to pause for some time
>   after request has finished so that server is not getting hit too much.

Also have a look at **unsubscribe$ and takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)** <- These are used to **free up memory** after component is destroyed, to **avoid memory leaks**. It is one of the best practices to do so.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { concatMap, takeUntil, delay } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public form = this.fb.group({
    input: ["", Validators.required]
  });

  private makeRequest$ = new Subject();
  private unsubscribe$ = new Subject();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.makeRequest$
      .pipe(
        delay(500),
        concatMap(item =>
          this.http.get(`http://localhost:6013/api/v1/test/buffer?data=${item}`)
        ),
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
      )
      .subscribe();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.unsubscribe$.next();
    this.unsubscribe$.complete();
  }

  public onSubmit() {
    this.makeRequest$.next(this.form.controls.input.value);
    this.form.reset();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an Angular guy, but will help you with a neat Javascript solution to your problem. Your problem is textbook example of [Javascript promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises). In Javascript, **a `Promise` is an object which may produce a single value sometime in the future**. I'm sure the statement above is difficult to grasp if you have never heard about this concept, but let's think with common sense. A `Promise` in Javascript is not dissimilar from a promise in real-life. If I promise you something, the following can occur:

- my promise is already fulfilled at the point when I promise it to you, in which case you can handle it
- my promise will be fulfilled some time later in the future
- in the future it will be evident that my promise was not fulfilled
- my promise will never be evaluated

These intuitive cases have analogue cases in programming when you work with promises.

Example for a promise:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

  setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 1000); // (*)

});
```

Example taken from https://javascript.info/promise-chaining

As you can see, the Promise constructor gets a `function` parameter, which in turn has a `resolve` and a `reject` parameter. Both `resolve` and `reject` are `functions`. `resolve` is invoked when the `Promise` is fulfilled, while `reject` is invoked when the `Promise` is rejected. In our case the body of the `Promise` contains a call to `setTimeout` which ensures that the `Promise` will be resolved one second later than the creation of the `Promise`.

So, what if a request is a `Promise` (intuitively it is a promise that you will get a response, whatever it is) and the next request is a next `Promise` and so on? Is there a way to chain promises? Of course, let's see the full example:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

  setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 1000); // (*)

}).then(function(result) { // (**)

  alert(result); // 1
  return result * 2;

}).then(function(result) { // (***)

  alert(result); // 2
  return result * 2;

}).then(function(result) {

  alert(result); // 4
  return result * 2;

});
```

As you probably have already guessed, your requests should be in the bodies of promises, chained by calling [then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then). For example:

```
function promiseBody(resolve, reject) {
    // send request
    // if successful, call resolve
    // if failed, call reject
}

var prom = new Promise(promiseBody); 

//this array contains requests to be called after the first
for (var req of requests) {
    prom = prom.then(promiseBody);
}
```

Chaining your promises like this is very neat and easy to understand and maintain. Of course, this is more of a theoretical answer, because you will need to define what `resolve`, `reject`, `promiseBody` and `requests` are looking alike in your specific case and also you will need to cope with the possible situation that one of the requests will never be answered for some reason, but once you understand that you have a very elegant way to proceed and will just have to figure out the details, you will be on the right track.

Of course, you can solve this in the traditional way, by chaining callbacks, but that's not very elegant. You can also solve this with Javascript generators and you will end up with something more elegant than the old school callback ([hell](http://callbackhell.com/)) solution, like:

```
function *myRequestHandler(request) {
    while (request) {
        send(request);
        request = yield;
    };
}
```

and ensuring that you pass a proper `request` when this is being called and whenever a callback is executed, `next()` is called, passing the `next` `request`.